Separating Columns into individual dataframes in R
I've found lots of information for doing something similar to what I want to do, but nothing that seems like it will do exactly what I want.
I'm trying to chop / split / cut up a dataframe so that each column is its own dataframe, keeping its column name and the rownames
To clarify, I am not trying to split the dataframe by variables in one column
This is as close as I've got using split.default and lapply
dge.norm_split <- split.default(dge.norm, colnames(dge.norm))
out <- lapply(dge.norm_split, cbind, dge.norm[1])

lapply(out, head, 3)

returns

$`/s-mcpb-ms03/union/is/PRO3/Data/50-0142/20230628_PRO3_FA_001_50-0142_ObesityWeightLoss_P00_QC-001.d`
    A matrix: 3 × 2 of type dbl 5672.1960   5672.196
    159.7225    5672.196
    1304.3856   5672.196
$`/s-mcpb-ms03/union/is/PRO3/Data/50-0142/20230628_PRO3_FA_012_50-0142_ObesityWeightLoss_P00_QC-002.d`
    A matrix: 3 × 2 of type dbl 28822.54894 5672.196
    837.19595   5672.196
    93.87691    5672.196
(truncacted)

So I think I've created a list containg each column as its own table, although  these should be 3x1 matrices and I don't why they are 3x2
I also can't figure out how to then extract each into its own variable without doing it manually (there are 29 so this is a bit laborious)
Some kind of for loop?
Solution:
Thanks everyone for responding. I tried your suggestions but in the end I took the long way round to get the output I was looking for:
s1 <- data.frame(dge.norm[,-c(2:6)])
s2 <- data.frame(dge.norm[,-c(1, 3:6)])
s3 <- data.frame(dge.norm[,-c(1:2, 4:6)])
s4 <- data.frame(dge.norm[,-c(1:3, 5:6)])
s5 <- data.frame(dge.norm[,-c(1:4, 6)])
s6 <- data.frame(dge.norm[,-c(1:5)])

s1$model <- rep(list('s1'), 337)
s2$model <- rep(list('s2'), 337)
s3$model <- rep(list('s3'), 337)
s4$model <- rep(list('s4'), 337)
s5$model <- rep(list('s5'), 337)
s6$model <- rep(list('s6'), 337)

colnames(s1) <- c('count', 'model')
colnames(s2) <- c('count', 'model')
colnames(s3) <- c('count', 'model')
colnames(s4) <- c('count', 'model')
colnames(s5) <- c('count', 'model')
colnames(s6) <- c('count', 'model')

What I had originally was a gene count matrix where rownames = genes and colnames = samples. I merged and stacked the count data for each sample into one column, which meant repeating rownames * number of samples, and added a new column corresponding to the sample

Please read about how to make a great R reproducible example and update your question accordingly. Include a sample of your data by pasting the output of dput(<your data frame>) into your post or dput(head(<your data frame>)) if you have a large data frame. If you cannot post your data, then post code for creating representative data. You will get better help if you add a reproducible example.

Here is one general way to do it: lapply(seq_len(ncol(mtcars)), \(x) mtcars[, x, drop = FALSE]). Replace mtcars with your data frame.

Similar to what @LMc suggested in a comment, you can subset by iterating over column names:
dfs <- lapply(names(iris), \(x) iris[x])

Result:
#> lapply(dfs, head)
[[1]]
  Sepal.Length
1          5.1
2          4.9
3          4.7
4          4.6
5          5.0
6          5.4

[[2]]
  Sepal.Width
1         3.5
2         3.0
3         3.2
4         3.1
5         3.6
6         3.9

[[3]]
  Petal.Length
1          1.4
2          1.4
3          1.3
4          1.5
5          1.4
6          1.7

[[4]]
  Petal.Width
1         0.2
2         0.2
3         0.2
4         0.2
5         0.2
6         0.4

[[5]]
  Species
1  setosa
2  setosa
3  setosa
4  setosa
5  setosa
6  setosa


split.default(iris, seq_along(iris)) # Thanks Rui B. for suggestion

Or with names() (turn first to factor to avoid reordering)
split.default(iris, factor(names(iris), names(iris)))

Or reorder after the fact (as suggested by LMc)
split.default(iris, names(iris))[names(iris)]


This is the simplest answer so far. And even simpler, split.default(iris, seq_along(iris)).

I've seen it used here on SO but can't remember seeing it in the documentation. I think you could also argue that zephryl has the simplest solution.

You could make it even simpler since split.default is basically the same lapply code as zephryl: split.default(iris, names(iris)). The list elements will also have more meaningful names.

@LMc that was my first idea but it will change the column order

True. I just want to highlight that this solution (using the names options) preserves the column names as list names too, which is pretty handy. You can preserve the order with split.default(iris, names(iris))[names(iris)]

Coerce each column to data.frame in a lapply loop, then assign the column names.
df_list <- mtcars |> lapply(as.data.frame)
df_list <- mapply(setNames, df_list, names(df_list), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

str(df_list)
#> List of 11
#>  $ mpg :'data.frame':    32 obs. of  1 variable:
#>   ..$ mpg: num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#>  $ cyl :'data.frame':    32 obs. of  1 variable:
#>   ..$ cyl: num [1:32] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
#>  $ disp:'data.frame':    32 obs. of  1 variable:
#>   ..$ disp: num [1:32] 160 160 108 258 360 ...
#>  $ hp  :'data.frame':    32 obs. of  1 variable:
#>   ..$ hp: num [1:32] 110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
#>  $ drat:'data.frame':    32 obs. of  1 variable:
#>   ..$ drat: num [1:32] 3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
#>  $ wt  :'data.frame':    32 obs. of  1 variable:
#>   ..$ wt: num [1:32] 2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
#>  $ qsec:'data.frame':    32 obs. of  1 variable:
#>   ..$ qsec: num [1:32] 16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
#>  $ vs  :'data.frame':    32 obs. of  1 variable:
#>   ..$ vs: num [1:32] 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
#>  $ am  :'data.frame':    32 obs. of  1 variable:
#>   ..$ am: num [1:32] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ gear:'data.frame':    32 obs. of  1 variable:
#>   ..$ gear: num [1:32] 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
#>  $ carb:'data.frame':    32 obs. of  1 variable:
#>   ..$ carb: num [1:32] 4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...

Created on 2024-05-24 with reprex v2.1.0
